# PHP set_time_limit(0) Makes Script Terminate Almost Instantly Instead of No Time Limit Imposed

Tags: php

Running PHP 7.4.3 on Ubuntu server.

`max_execution_time` set to `30` in server `php.ini`.

Expected behavior of overriding this with `set_time_limit(0);` or `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` according to PHP documentation would be to remove any time limit imposed.

But instead of that, execution of script is stopped very shortly (like 100 ms or so of execution time) after the time limit got changed to `0` with following PHP error message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/test/index.php on line 9
```

In this test script there is an (intentional) infinite loop on line 9.

Setting a time limit now of e. g. 5 seconds, however, works as expected and script is stopped after 5 seconds of execution time. Only setting the maximum execution time to 0 seconds (= and thus infinite) leads to the opposite effect of essentially terminating the script almost immediately.

For reference, full `phpinfo()` output can be found here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aupd_UOJ5t9Jh9AEH2lsZV3OhTNJmg?e=ntGdDs

What could cause such an unexpected behavior?

Thanks a lot for any tip on this topic!

Comment: And what exactly is on line 9? My guess is an infinite loop

Comment: Hello Jaquarh, thanks for your reply. This PHP script is just for testing after how much execution time the script gets terminated. So yes, in line 9 I've intentionally added an infinite loop. Now when I set the time limit to e. g. "5" secs, it stops the script after 5 secs. (as expected), but when I set the time limit to "0", it stops it immediately instead of waiting forever (till I stop the script manually). What is the reason for that? Andreas.